# Can't change scrollbar values

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrolltop

I've made a simple code to change the value of a scrollbar along with `document.scrollTop` but i can't get it to work.

```
var scroll = document.scrollTop; 
var container = document.getElementById('test');
container.innerHTML = scroll;

 var pb = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
 pb.value = 2;
 var change = function()
 {   pb.value = 2;
     pb.value++;
 };

 if (scroll > 0){
     change();
 };
```

Can someone tell me where i've made a mistake(s) ?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: it would be better if you posted at least some part of html

Comment: `document.scrollTop` is undefined - use `document.body.scrollTop`.

Comment: ItsGreg-Why is it undefined ? I mean why document.scrollTop is not right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You haven't shared many details in your post but from what you have posted we can notice that you have some problems in your current code:

- As stated in comments you need to use `document.body.scrollTop`
  because `document.scrollTop` is `undefined` as the scroll is attached
  to document `body` and not to the `document` itself.
- And with your actual code you are not changing the progress bar value, because the `change()` function isn't attached to any event but it's just called on document load.

**Solution:**

If you want to change the progress bar value when the page is scrolled, you need to do it in the `onscroll` event of the `body`.

**Demo:**

I made a sample Demo to show you how it should work, and how the progress bar is changing when we scroll in the view:

```js
document.body.onscroll = function() {
  var pb = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
  var fullHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  var value = 100 - (document.body.scrollTop / fullHeight) * 100;
  pb.value = value;
};
```

```css
#progress-bar {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:250px; height:1400px">
  <progress id="progress-bar" value="100" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

The above function is attached to the `onscroll` event of the `document.body`, and whenever the body is scrolled it calculates the scrolled height (`document.body.scrollTop`) compared with the full scrollable height (`document.body.scrollHeight`) and put this value in the progress bar.

Comment: Ok,but is it always nescessary to use document.body.scrollTop instead of document.scrollTop ? Because i can't figure out what's the difference ?

Comment: @Atomix yes because there isn't  `document.scrollTop`, `document` does not have a `scrollTop` property, because scroll is applied to the `body` as it holds the page view.